URLSessionTaskDelegate authentication challenge function not being called
I'm trying to connect to a smart switch using URLSession. The switch uses http Digest Authentication which should trigger a call to delegate function urlSession(_: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive: URLAuthenticationChallenge ..., but that function is never called.
In testing my code using a Digest Authentication testing website the challenge delegate function is called as expected. So it seems that URLSession is not responding to the way the smart switch company implemented Digest Authentication.
I can successfully connect to the switch by manually handling the Digest Authentication by building and setting the Authentication header, but this only works in an Xcode playground. In an iOS app setting the Authentication header has no effect, as noted in the documentation.
My question is: Is there another way to add the Digest Authentication userId and password to the URLSession other than in an Authentication Challenge delegate method?
If not, is there another, perhaps lower level, way to set the Authentication header?
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Here is some testing code that can be run in an Xcode playground:
import Foundation
class Foo: NSObject {
    public func connect() {
        // this url calls the challenge delegate function
        let urlS = "http://httpbin.org/digest-auth/undefined/undefined/undefined"
        
        // this smart switch url does not call the challenge delegate function
        // let urlS = "http://192.168.1.99/relay/0?turn=on&timer=30"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlS) else {
            return
        }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        session.dataTask(with: request).resume()
    }
}

extension Foo: URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    func urlSession(_: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void)
    {
        print("Authentication Challenge Delegate Called")
        // never gets called
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        let msg = (error != nil) ? String(describing: error) : "nil"
        print("something went wrong: \(msg)")
        // gets called with error = nil
    }
}

let foo = Foo()
foo.connect()


Note Apple requires https connections. To use http, you need to set the "NSAppTransportSecurity"
in your Info.plist to allow http connection to the desired servers. Have you done that for all your http?

Thanks for this suggestion @workingdog-support-ukraine. I tried it but did not see any different results. I enabled 'Allows Local Networking' and 'Allow Arbitrary Loads'.

Seeing let foo = Foo(); foo.connect(): Where is that written exactly? Are you using a writing a kind of Script? I mean is "Foo" still in memory when the delegate is called? If not, that would explain it. In Playground, to make it work, you need to use PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true if your full code is as such. But in a Script that's not how it's done, and currently with just that code, it's equivalent to indefiniteExecution = false.

thanks @Larme the above simplified code is for a playground environment, but I got the same results when running an app in debug mode on a simulator. Taking your advise, I tried adding import PlaygroundSupport and PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true to the top of the playground code but it had no effect. Also just running the code above as written calls one or the other delegate method based on which url string is uncommented.

Is it possible that the device is replying with a redirect to an authentication page or something, rather than sending a 401 as one would normally expect?  The default is to follow redirects, and that might be throwing things off.  Try rejecting redirects, though I doubt that will help.  Also, make sure you're not half-implementing any other callbacks.  For example, if it had called your auth handler with a different auth type and you returned without performing default handling or some other action, the whole stack would go sideways and future calls wouldn't happen.

Thanks @dgatwood . I added the redirect delegate method but still no joy. The smart switch server is returning a 401 as it is supposed to do. Digest Authentication works just fine on the device when accessing it from a web browser or from curl. It just doesn't work from a URLSession.

Let's clarify: The httpbin works in Playground? In iOS App? The 192 one works in Playground? In iOS App?

@Larme httpbin works as expected using the above code in App and Playground. The Smart Switch's built in webserver interface (the 192) does not work in App or Playground using URLSessionTaskDelegate methods. The only way I could get the 192 to work was by manually setting the Authorization header while in a Playground, which is not allowed in an App. This is a bug that I am reporting to Apple. My guess is URLSession is doing some fancy networking protocol stuff expecting that web servers are sophisticated and react accordingly, but this one isn't and can't.

Thank you for the clarification, as I read a few times the question and couldn't see what was working and what wasn't, if it was exclusively the custom server (192) that was having the issue or not...

Since it is unencrypted HTTP, you should be able to use tcpdump to sniff the communication and see if there's anything weird happening.  I doubt you'll find anything, but maybe something in the headers might be a clue.  But just to be sure, you're not seeing the method get called at all — not even once?  Because normally that would get called at least once before the request is issued in the first place, followed by additional calls.  The lack of a NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling call in the callback is a red flag.

@dgatwood Thanks for the tip about tcpdump. I'll try that. NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling is not being called at all when connecting to the smart switch built in web server.

After much work on this I can't figure out why URLSession does not recognize the Smart Switch web server's authentication challenge. Since URLSession is a black box, I built a work around solution by going lower level using Apple's Network framework. Using this method I made a simple http client which allows me to manually set the Digest Authentication header. Playground runable code is below with a working example of how to use it at the bottom of the code.
Maybe someday I'll turn this into a proper library package.
Thanks to everyone who commented.
import Foundation
import Network
import CryptoKit

class SimpleHTTP: NSObject {
    
    /**
     * Interface vars, structures and classes
     */
    
    struct HTTPContent {
        var statusCode: Int = 0
        var status: String = ""
        var headers: [(name: String, value: String)] = []
        var digestAuthParts: (nonce: String, realm: String, algorithm: String) = ("", "", "")
        var body: String = ""
    }
    
    class DigestSession {
        let hostIP4: String
        let user: String
        let password: String
        let cNonce = SimpleHTTP.randomHexString(length: 16)
        private var nc = 0
        let realm: String
        let nonce: String
        let algorithm: String
        
        init(hostIP4: String, user: String, password: String, unauthHttpContent: HTTPContent) {
            self.hostIP4 = hostIP4
            self.user = user
            self.password = password
            realm = unauthHttpContent.digestAuthParts.realm
            self.nonce = unauthHttpContent.digestAuthParts.nonce
            self.algorithm = unauthHttpContent.digestAuthParts.nonce
        }
        
        func getNextNC() -> Int {
            self.nc += 1
            return self.nc
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Interface Calls
     */
    
    static func httpGet(hostIP4: String, path: String, authorization: String, callback: @escaping (Int, String) -> Void) {
        
        guard let ipAddress = IPv4Address(hostIP4) else {
            print("SimpleHTTP: Invalid hostIP4 parameter")
            callback(-1, "Invalid hostIP4 parameter")
            return
        }
        let endPoint = NWEndpoint.Host.ipv4(ipAddress)
        let connection = NWConnection(host: .ipv4(ipAddress), port: .http, using: .tcp)
        
        connection.stateUpdateHandler = { newState in
            switch newState {
            case .cancelled:
                break
            case .preparing:
                break
            case .setup:
                break
            case .waiting(let error):
                print("connection waiting with \(error)")
                connection.cancel()
            case .ready:
                SimpleHTTP.sendMessage(connection: connection, hostIP4:hostIP4, path: path, authorization: authorization, callback: callback)
            case .failed(let error):
                print("connection failed with \(error)")
                connection.cancel()
            @unknown default:
                break
            }
        }
        connection.start(queue: .main)
    }
    
    private static func sendMessage(connection: NWConnection, hostIP4: String = "", path: String = "", authorization: String = "", callback: @escaping (Int, String) -> Void) {
        var message = "GET \(path) HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        message += "host: \(hostIP4)\r\n"
        if authorization != "" {
            message += "Authorization: \(authorization)\r\n"
        }
        message += "User-Agent: simpleHttp/1.0.0\r\n"
        message += "Accept: */*\r\n"
        message += "\r\n"   // required to seperate headers from body

        let messageD = Data(message.utf8)
        connection.send(content: messageD, completion: .contentProcessed( { error in
            if let error = error {
                callback(-2, error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            connection.receiveMessage { content, contentContext, isComplete, error in
                if let error = error {
                    callback(-3, error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                if let content = content {
                    let contentS = String(data: content, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
                    callback(0, contentS)
                } else {
                    callback(0, "No Content")
                }
                connection.cancel()
            }
        }))
    }
    
    static func formatReply(content: String) -> SimpleHTTP.HTTPContent {
        var outC = SimpleHTTP.HTTPContent()
        
        // seperate headers and body
        let firstDoubleCRLFRange = content.firstRange(of: "\r\n\r\n")
        let headers = content[..<(firstDoubleCRLFRange?.lowerBound ?? content.endIndex)]
        outC.body = String(content[(firstDoubleCRLFRange?.upperBound ?? content.endIndex)...])
        
        // read headers
        let contentLines = headers.split(separator: "\r\n")
        for line in contentLines {
            if line.hasPrefix("HTTP/") {
                let parts = String(line).split(separator: " ")
                if parts.count > 2 {
                    outC.statusCode = Int(parts[1]) ?? 0
                    outC.status = String(parts[2])
                }
            } else {
                let parts = String(line).split(separator: ": ")
                if parts.count == 2 {
                    let header = (name: String(parts[0]), value: String(parts[1]))
                    outC.headers.append(header)
                    if header.name == "WWW-Authenticate" &&
                        header.value.firstRange(of: "Digest ") != nil {
                        outC.digestAuthParts = SimpleHTTP.getDigestVars(auth: header.value)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        return outC
    }
    
    private static func getDigestVars(auth: String) -> (nonce: String, realm: String, algorithm: String) {
        var outValue = (nonce: "", realm: "", algorithm: "")
        let afterDigest = auth.dropFirst("Digest ".lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8))
        let parts = afterDigest.split(separator: ", ")
        for part in parts {
            let pair = part.split(separator: "=")
            if pair.endIndex > 1 {
                let key = pair[0]
                let value = pair[1]
                let noQuotesValue = value.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
                
                if key == "nonce" {
                    outValue.nonce = noQuotesValue
                } else if key == "realm" {
                    outValue.realm = noQuotesValue
                } else if key == "algorithm" {
                    outValue.algorithm = noQuotesValue
                }
            }
        }
        return outValue
    }
    
    static func makeAuthHeader(path: String, session: DigestSession) -> String {
        var outS = "Digest "
        outS += "username=\"\(session.user)\", "
        outS += "realm=\"\(session.realm)\", "
        outS += "nonce=\"\(session.nonce)\", "
        outS += "uri=\"\(path)\", "
        outS += "algorithm=SHA-256, "
        let nc = String(format: "%08d", session.getNextNC())
        let responseHash = makeResponseHash(path: path, session: session, nc: nc)
        outS += "response=\"\(responseHash)\", "
        outS += "qop=auth, "
        outS += "nc=\(nc), "
        outS += "cnonce=\"\(session.cNonce)\""
        return outS;
    }

    private static func makeResponseHash(path: String, session: DigestSession, nc: String) -> String {
        let h1Parts = "\(session.user):\(session.realm):\(session.password)"
        let ha1 = SimpleHTTP.sha256Hash(value: h1Parts)
        
        let h2Parts = "GET:\(path)"
        let ha2 = SimpleHTTP.sha256Hash(value: h2Parts)
        
        let rspParts = "\(ha1):\(session.nonce):\(nc):\(session.cNonce):auth:\(ha2)"
        let outS = SimpleHTTP.sha256Hash(value: rspParts)
        
        return outS
    }
    
    static func randomHexString(length: Int) -> String {
        let halfLength = (length/2)*2 == length ? length/2 : (length/2) + 1
        var bytes = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: halfLength)
        _ = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, halfLength, &bytes)
        var outS:String = ""
        for value in bytes {
            let intValue = Int(value)
            let positiveVal = intValue + 128
            outS += String(format: "%02X", positiveVal)
        }
        return String(outS.prefix(length))
    }
    
    static func sha256Hash(value: String) -> String {
        let hash = SHA256.hash(data: Data(value.utf8))
        let outS = hash.compactMap { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
        return outS
    }
}

var digestSession: SimpleHTTP.DigestSession?
let hostIP4 = "192.168.1.99"
let path = "/relay/0?turn=on&timer=30"
let user = "foo"
let password = "bar"

SimpleHTTP.httpGet(
    hostIP4: hostIP4,
    path: path,
    authorization: "") { statusCode, contentS in
        let content = SimpleHTTP.formatReply(content: contentS)
        print("statusCode without auth header: \(statusCode)")
        if content.statusCode == 401 && digestSession == nil {
            digestSession = SimpleHTTP.DigestSession(hostIP4: hostIP4, user: user, password: password, unauthHttpContent: content)
            let authHeaderValue = SimpleHTTP.makeAuthHeader(path: path, session: digestSession!)
            SimpleHTTP.httpGet(hostIP4: hostIP4, path: path, authorization: authHeaderValue) { statusCode, contentS in
                print("statusCode using auth header: \(statusCode)")
            }
        }
    }

